# Query taking more space on /tmp dir and more load & time while executing

Tags: mysql

Please find the below query which is taking more time , load & space on `/tmp/` directory

```
SELECT DISTINCT pil.pilsellersku,
  pil.pilname,
  pbi.pbicode,
  '',
  group_concat(DISTINCT ppt.pptcmtrfnum SEPARATOR ','),
  pbi.pbibrand,
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  pil.pilicmdisplaycolor,
  pbi.pbidesc,
  pbi.pbiattrlabel1,
  pil.pilattrvalue1,
  pbi.pbiattrlabel2,
  pil.pilattrvalue2,
  pbi.pbiattrlabel3,
  pil.pilattrvalue3,
  '',
  pod.PODISBESTSELLER,
  pod.PODISNEWARRIVAL,
  pod.PODISCHOSEN,
  pit.pitzoomimage,
  pit.pitimage,
  pil.pilimage,
  pit.pitthumbnailimage,
  pit.pitthumbnailimage,
  pil.pilmrp,
  pod.PODMARGIN,
  pod.PODRETCOST,
  pbi.pbidiscvalue,
  pbi.pbidiscinvalue,
  pil.pilvat,
  pil.pilstockqty,
  pil.PILASRTGRP,
  sot.sotsomrfnum,
  group_concat(DISTINCT ppm.PPMPMTRFNUM SEPARATOR ','),
  ccg.ccgrfnum,
  pil.pilactive,
  pbi.pbiisgiftwrap,
  pbi.pbigiftwrapcharge,
  pbi.pbiispreffdate,
  pbi.pbissirfnum,
  pod.PODSTSL,
  '',
  '',
  pod.PODPVC,
  pod.PODWSPRICE,
  pod.PODODV,
  pod.PODSEQ,
  pod.PODSTCODE,
  pod.PODTAXATTRI,
  pod.PODPRODUNIT,
  pod.PODSTDCOST,
  pod.PODMATCODE,
  pod.PODWEEK,
  pod.PODYEAR,
  pod.PODDYRWK,
  pod.PODISBESTBUY,
  pbi.isonline,
  pbi.pbiseqnum,
  scm.scmcode
FROM Ismpbi pbi
LEFT JOIN ISMPIL pil
  ON pbi.pbirfnum = pil.pilpbirfnum
LEFT JOIN ISMPIT pit
  ON pbi.pbirfnum = pit.pitpbirfnum
    AND pit.pitviewseq = 1
LEFT JOIN ISMSOT sot
  ON sot.sotpbirfnum = pbi.pbirfnum
LEFT JOIN OTHPOD pod
  ON pod.podpbirfnum = pbi.pbirfnum
LEFT JOIN ISMPPM ppm
  ON ppm.ppmpbirfnum = pbi.pbirfnum
LEFT JOIN ISMPPT ppt
  ON ppt.pptpbirfnum = pbi.pbirfnum
LEFT JOIN ISMCCG ccg
  ON pbi.pbiccgrfnum = ccg.ccgrfnum
LEFT JOIN OCTSCM scm
  ON pbi.pbiscmrfnum = scm.scmrfnum
WHERE pbi.PBIBRAND = 35
GROUP BY pil.pilsellersku;
```

In the above query all joined columns & where condition columns( i.e `pbi.PBIBRAND` & `pit.pitviewseq`) are indexed.

And Explain Statement as follows.

```
 +----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+ 
 | id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                             | key          | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra                                        |
 +----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+ 
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | pbi   | ref    | IDX_PBIBRAND                              | IDX_PBIBRAND | 9       | const                   | 4420 | Usingwhere; Using temporary; Using filesort  |  
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | pil   | ref    | IDX_PILPBI                                | IDX_PILPBI   | 8       | apparel.pbi.PBIRFNUM    |    3 |                                              | 
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | pit   | ref    | IDX_PITPBI                                | IDX_PITPBI   | 8       | apparel.pbi.PBIRFNUM    |    9 |                                              |  
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | sot   | ref    | PRIMARY,SOTPBIRFNUM,IDX_SOTPBI            | PRIMARY      | 8       | apparel.pbi.PBIRFNUM    |    1 | Using index                                  |
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | pod   | ref    | PODPBIRFNUM,FK_POD_PBI,FK8B908042468F70B6 | PODPBIRFNUM  | 9       | apparel.pbi.PBIRFNUM    |    1 |                                              |
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | ppm   | ref    | IDX_PPMPBI                                | IDX_PPMPBI   | 8       | apparel.pbi.PBIRFNUM    |    1 |                                              |  
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | ppt   | ref    | PRIMARY,PPTPBIRFNUM,IDX_PPTPBI            | PRIMARY      | 8       | apparel.pbi.PBIRFNUM    |    1 | Using index                                  |  
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | ccg   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,CCGRFNUM                          | PRIMARY      | 8       | apparel.pbi.PBICCGRFNUM |    1 | Using index                                  | 
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | scm   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,SCMRFNUM                          | PRIMARY      | 8       | apparel.pbi.PBISCMRFNUM |    1 |                                              | 
 +----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
 9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The above query is taking time almost 17 minutes. Load on server is going across 15 and `/tmp/` direction on disk level is consuming 21 GB.

Can any one suggest to optimize & modifying the query to get the result.

Comment: please try to format your code next time. people might not be willing to help your if you're not even trying to present readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Your overall query looks simple and sound... Your primary table of ISMPBI is all left-joined to the others which implies to me that they are more secondary / lookup tables.

To help, I would to the following...  Add "STRAIGHT_JOIN" keyword to your select

SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN DISTINCT ....

For your ISMPBI table, make sure it has an index on  (PBIBRAND)

Make sure that all your other tables have index on their respective "JOIN" column names...  For the ISMPIT table, have index on (PITBIRFNUM, PITVIEWSEQ) -- since you have an AND clause for PitViewSeq

EDIT -- prequery test option..

Can you run this as a prequery to see what performance IT has vs the join to every table...

```
         SELECT
              pbi.pbirfnum,
              pil.pilsellersku,
              group_concat(DISTINCT ppt.pptcmtrfnum SEPARATOR ',') as PPT_Values,
              group_concat(DISTINCT ppm.PPMPMTRFNUM SEPARATOR ',') as PPM_Values
           FROM 
              Ismpbi pbi
                 LEFT JOIN ISMPIL pil
                    ON pbi.pbirfnum = pil.pilpbirfnum
                 LEFT JOIN ISMPPM ppm
                    ON pbi.pbirfnum = ppm.ppmpbirfnum
                 LEFT JOIN ISMPPT ppt
                    ON pbi.pbirfnum = ppt.pptpbirfnum 
           WHERE 
              pbi.PBIBRAND = 35
           GROUP BY 
              pbi.pbirfnum,
              pil.pilsellersku
```

Comment: Already every join columns are indexed and PITBIRFNUM, PITVIEWSEQ also indexed.Still It is executing as same.

Comment: @user2435371, in your ISMPBI table, what is the PRIMARY (unique auto-increment) column of the table.  I'm trying to think of an alternative pre-query solution for you.

Comment: @user2435371, I've put a test query for you to try without all the other joins.  Can you see how IT runs?  Also, still need PRIMARY column from ISMPBI per other comment above.